# PhD opportunities in Spring in US universities

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I am facing a dilemma regarding whether or not to apply for Spring for PhD programs at some universities in US. What are the pros and cons of applying for PhD or MS programs in Spring?

Answer (score 5):

Most PhD programs, and many master's programs, in the US only offer one admissions cycle per year, with programs starting in the fall. This is in part because of the PhD program encompassing classwork as well as research.

The main issue that speaks against spring admissions is that in most programs, the coursework begins in the fall semester, and any "sequences" (where course Y depends on course X) will often begin in the fall semester. Thus, starting in the spring semester may mean that your coursework phase will need to extend longer, so there's no real advantage between starting in the spring and waiting until the following fall.

Where there might be an advantage is if you are able to use some of the time for finding a research group (if that is necessary for a research thesis for the master's degree); in some cases, you could even get a head start on the thesis work, which could allow you to finish somewhat faster.

Comment: Also, most of the funding decisions, both departmental and research-group, are made on an academic-year cycle.

Comment: @paulgarrett: Yes, but a grant award funding additional students can come in at virtually any time.

Comment: In mathematics, the funding cycle is academic-year, so unless someone else got _de_ -funded, chances are slim that there'd be an extra "unit" of support just lying around.

Comment: @paulgarrett: In my experience, NSF funding can be timed to hit just about any day of the year, and you are certainly free to write almost any start date into your own grants. I have grants that start all over the map, though many of them start in the US summer or early fall.

Comment: @BillBarth, well, NSF math gives the impression of having a precise cycle that they like. Maybe I've read too much into it.

Comment: @paulgarrett, it could be that MPS and mathematics in particular may have a more defined process, but NSF in general isn't that specific in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I started grad school in the spring of 1998, immediately after I finished my undergrad the previous fall. I happened to be continuing at the same university with an advisor that I had worked with some during undergrad. Aeismail is probably right, but it can be done. I spent the time starting to do a little research and taking a few interesting classes that were outside the standard new-graduate student sequence. You probably won't shorten your time in grad school with a spring start, but you might enjoy it more with a warm-up semester. If you can make $50k+ by waiting til the fall, that might be worth it.

Comment: Were you formally admitted through a standard admissions process, or was it an informal arrangement since you were "staying put?"

Comment: Hard to say. I certainly did a formal application, but I can't recall the rest. It's been a long time.